# Using corresponding value of picturebox to delete access record

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hey I've created a dictionary that I use to create pictureboxes. Each picturebox has a number, which I then want to use to remove the access record, corresponding to that number. So I've got the dictionary working, but how do I get the number that corresponds to each picturebox? Here is my code (everything is defined, like cardsdictionary as dictionary):

```
   Public Sub bigpictureloader()
       'Dim list As New List(Of String)(cardsdictionary.Keys)

       Dim cardcount As Integer
       cardcount = 0
       counter += 1
       cardcount = counter
       'Dim cards As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
       cardsdictionary.Add(imageurltxt.Text, cardcount)


       'Create a placeholder variable
       Dim cardPictureBox As PictureBox
       Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)
       'Loop through every selected card URL
       For Each pair In cardsdictionary
           'Create a new PictureBox
           cardPictureBox = New PictureBox()
           cardPictureBox.Size = New Size(100, 100)
           cardPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
           cardPictureBox.WaitOnLoad = False
           AddHandler cardPictureBox.Click, AddressOf imagehandler

           'Add the PictureBox to the Form
           Me.Controls.Add(cardPictureBox)
           'MsgBox(cardsdict.Values.ToString)

           If imageurltxt.Text = "" Then
               cardPictureBox = Nothing
           Else

               cardPictureBox.LoadAsync(pair.Key)
               TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cardPictureBox, 0, 0)

           End If

       Next

   End Sub
```

```
    Private Sub testdelete()
        'THIS SAVES TO THE DEBUG ACCESS DATABASE!!!!!
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;")
            Using command As New OleDbCommand("Delete From cmon11 Where ID= @ID;", conn)
'pair.value is what I think will work, but doesn't currently               
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(pair.value)
                conn.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using


    End Sub
```

this is my imagehandler!!!

```
Private Sub imagehandler(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       testdelete()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Tag` property of the PictureBox to store the ID. You populate this property when you create the PictureBox.

In your handler you can do something like this:

```
Private Sub imagehandler(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
           Dim myPictureBox As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
           'Now you can access myPictureBox.Tag and pass it into your delete function
           Dim id As Integer = -1
           If Int32.TryParse(myPictureBox.Tag, id) = True Then
                testdelete(id)
           End If           
        End Sub


Private Sub testdelete(id As Integer)
        'THIS SAVES TO THE DEBUG ACCESS DATABASE!!!!!
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;")
            Using command As New OleDbCommand("Delete From cmon11 Where ID= @ID;", conn)
'pair.value is what I think will work, but doesn't currently               
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id
                conn.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

testdelete doesn't know which imasge you want to delete.  Using Michael's suggestion you want:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(Me.Tag)
```

By the way your use of counter and cardcount can be cleaned up substantially.

Comment: Yeah, I would do away with the dict altogether because the PictureBox can already store both values.